# Old PyMC3 style grouping traceplot plotted with Arviz

Tags: python, pymc3, arviz

I have an old blogpost where I am training a PyMC3 model. You can find the blogpost [here](https://koaning.io/posts/vi-drives-me-nuts/) but the gist of the model is shown below.

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    mu_intercept = pm.Normal('mu_intercept', mu=40, sd=5)
    mu_slope = pm.HalfNormal('mu_slope', 10, shape=(n_diets,))
    mu = mu_intercept + mu_slope[df.diet-1] * df.time
    sigma_intercept = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_intercept', sd=2)
    sigma_slope = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_slope', sd=2, shape=n_diets)
    sigma = sigma_intercept + sigma_slope[df.diet-1] * df.time
    weight = pm.Normal('weight', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=df.weight)
    approx = pm.fit(20000, random_seed=42, method="fullrank_advi")
```

In this dataset I'm estimating the effect of `Diet` on the weight of chickens. This is what the traceplot looks like.

[image: traceplot]

Look at how pretty it is! Each diet has its own line! Beautiful!

### Arviz Changes

This traceplot was made using the older PyMC3 API. Nowadays this functionality has moved to arviz. So tried redo-ing this work but ... the plot looks very different.

[image]

The code that I'm using here is *slightly* different. I'm using `pm.Data` now but I doubt that's supposed to cause this difference.

```py
with pm.Model() as mod: 
    time_in = pm.Data("time_in", df['time'].astype(float))
    diet_in = pm.Data("diet_in", dummies)
    
    intercept = pm.Normal("intercept", 0, 2)
    time_effect = pm.Normal("time_weight_effect", 0, 2, shape=(4,))
    diet = pm.Categorical("diet", p=[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], shape=(4,), observed=diet_in)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", 2)
    sigma_time_effect = pm.HalfNormal("time_sigma_effect", 2, shape=(4,))
    weight = pm.Normal("weight", 
                       mu=intercept + time_effect.dot(diet_in.T)*time_in, 
                       sd=sigma + sigma_time_effect.dot(diet_in.T)*time_in, 
                       observed=df.weight)
    trace = pm.sample(5000, return_inferencedata=True)
```

What do I need to do to get the different colors per DIET back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a parameter for it in the new `plot_trace` function. This does the trick;

```py
az.plot_trace(trace, compact=True)
```